# Select the rows where at least x columns are above average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but may have more columns in the future):

```
Serial No    2015    2016    2017    2018
 1            20      30       25      35
 2            22      35       47      30
```

I wish to select the rows where the values in at least 3 out of 4 columns are above the average value of that column. I would greatly appreciate a more flexible answer that e.g can be easily edited to make it 2 out of 4 columns or 4 out of 6 columns, or perhaps above average by at least 5%

If I wanted all of the columns, I could simply write something like `df.2015>df.2015.mean() & df.2016>df.2016.mean()` and so on, but if I want to see at least x out of y columns, this approach won't work without a catastrophically complicated logic.

Is there any relatively simple way to do this, or is this really as difficult a problem as I fear it is? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(size=(10, 3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df[np.sum(df > df.mean(), axis=1) > 2]  # 2 is the argument that 
                                        # defines the number of values that 
                                        # should be above the mean
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer - but won't this also take into account the "Serial No" column? (Which isn't the index here.)

Comment: @Raddaya: Yes, indeed it would. If you want to restrict the column to which you want to apply the check to, you could write `np.sum(df[['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']] > df[['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']].mean(), axis=1)`.